# Django aggregate not returning any value

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a view:

```
class ExpenseDateFilterTotal(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        queryset =  Expenses.objects.all().aggregate(total=Sum('day'))
        return HttpResponse(queryset, content_type="application/json")
```

access from the url:

```
url(r'^expenses_date_filter_total/$', expenses.ExpenseDateFilterTotal.as_view()),
```

I am expecting a response equal to:

```
{"total":234}
```

but all I am getting is:

```
total
```

I am new to django and i read the api doc at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/. The `count()` functions are working perfectly. But the sum/avg/max etc is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is fine with the queryset - you just return the wrong Response object. As you use DRF, read [this docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#creating-responses) and [this tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/) for further information.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

class ExpenseDateFilterTotal(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        queryset =  Expenses.objects.all().aggregate(total=Sum('day'))
        return Response(queryset, content_type="application/json")
```